# Want to know all the assigned CSS to an element

Tags: html, css

Hii I have a blog and I want to add an element the same one can see at http://css-tricks.com/ footer ( When U scroll down will see a paragraph written about Codepen and ShopTalk) I want to add that to my blog's footer I have the HTML but I don't know what CSS to add.

The HTML I have is

```
<div class="bottom-footer-part footer-codepen">
  <a class="footer-logo" href="http://codepen.io">
    <img alt="CodePen Logo" src="http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/CSS-Tricks-10/images/footer-logo-codepen.png">
  </a>
  <p>
    <a href="http://codepen.io">
      CodePen
    </a>
    is a social code playground for web designers and developers. Build demos, find inspiration, or troubleshoot code. With <a href="http://blog.codepen.io/documentation/pro-features/">CodePen PRO</a> you can teach students, pair program, host files, and more!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="bottom-footer-part footer-shoptalk">
  <a class="footer-logo" href="http://shoptalkshow.com">
    <img alt="ShopTalk Logo" src="http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/CSS-Tricks-10/images/footer-logo-shoptalk.png">
  </a>
  <p>
    <a href="http://shoptalkshow.com">
      ShopTalk
    </a>
     is a podcast about all things web design and development hosted by Dave Rupert and me. The show is recorded live and covers the week in #hotdrama and listener Q&amp;A.
   </p>
</div>
```

Please See DO NO Recomment me to use Firebug I have tried but I am unable to find all the CSS assigned.

Comment: You don't have any yours CSS for this html?

Comment: He's copying from css-tricks. basically he wants to add what css-tricks.com has into his own blog.

Comment: In Chrome this will show all the CSS rules applied in an element: Right click on the element -> Inspect Element -> Computed Styles -> Show Inherited

Answer (score 3):

Simplicity of DOM fetching:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('textBox1').style);
```

Check your Developer Tool and see all the object's properties. You can loop through them if needed.

Result on my div:

```
CSSStyleDeclaration
0: "color"
alignmentBaseline: ""
background: ""
backgroundAttachment: ""
backgroundClip: ""
backgroundColor: ""
backgroundImage: ""
backgroundOrigin: ""
backgroundPosition: ""
backgroundPositionX: ""
backgroundPositionY: ""
backgroundRepeat: ""
backgroundRepeatX: ""
backgroundRepeatY: ""
backgroundSize: ""
baselineShift: ""
border: ""
borderBottom: ""
borderBottomColor: ""
borderBottomLeftRadius: ""
borderBottomRightRadius: ""
borderBottomStyle: ""
borderBottomWidth: ""
borderCollapse: ""
borderColor: ""
borderImage: ""
borderImageOutset: ""
borderImageRepeat: ""
borderImageSlice: ""
borderImageSource: ""
borderImageWidth: ""
borderLeft: ""
borderLeftColor: ""
borderLeftStyle: ""
borderLeftWidth: ""
borderRadius: ""
borderRight: ""
borderRightColor: ""
borderRightStyle: ""
borderRightWidth: ""
borderSpacing: ""
borderStyle: ""
borderTop: ""
borderTopColor: ""
borderTopLeftRadius: ""
borderTopRightRadius: ""
borderTopStyle: ""
borderTopWidth: ""
borderWidth: ""
bottom: ""
boxShadow: ""
boxSizing: ""
captionSide: ""
clear: ""
clip: ""
clipPath: ""
clipRule: ""
color: "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
colorInterpolation: ""
colorInterpolationFilters: ""
colorProfile: ""
colorRendering: ""
constructor: CSSStyleDeclarationConstructor
content: ""
counterIncrement: ""
counterReset: ""
cssText: "color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "
cursor: ""
direction: ""
display: ""
dominantBaseline: ""
emptyCells: ""
enableBackground: ""
fill: ""
fillOpacity: ""
fillRule: ""
filter: ""
float: ""
floodColor: ""
floodOpacity: ""
font: ""
fontFamily: ""
fontSize: ""
fontStretch: ""
fontStyle: ""
fontVariant: ""
fontWeight: ""
glyphOrientationHorizontal: ""
glyphOrientationVertical: ""
height: ""
imageRendering: ""
kerning: ""
left: ""
length: 1
letterSpacing: ""
lightingColor: ""
lineHeight: ""
listStyle: ""
listStyleImage: ""
listStylePosition: ""
listStyleType: ""
margin: ""
marginBottom: ""
marginLeft: ""
marginRight: ""
marginTop: ""
marker: ""
markerEnd: ""
markerMid: ""
markerStart: ""
mask: ""
maxHeight: ""
maxWidth: ""
minHeight: ""
minWidth: ""
opacity: ""
orphans: ""
outline: ""
outlineColor: ""
outlineOffset: ""
outlineStyle: ""
outlineWidth: ""
overflow: ""
overflowX: ""
overflowY: ""
padding: ""
paddingBottom: ""
paddingLeft: ""
paddingRight: ""
paddingTop: ""
page: ""
pageBreakAfter: ""
pageBreakBefore: ""
pageBreakInside: ""
parentRule: null
pointerEvents: ""
position: ""
quotes: ""
resize: ""
right: ""
shapeRendering: ""
size: ""
speak: ""
src: ""
stopColor: ""
stopOpacity: ""
stroke: ""
strokeDasharray: ""
strokeDashoffset: ""
strokeLinecap: ""
strokeLinejoin: ""
strokeMiterlimit: ""
strokeOpacity: ""
strokeWidth: ""
tableLayout: ""
textAlign: ""
textAnchor: ""
textDecoration: ""
textIndent: ""
textLineThrough: ""
textLineThroughColor: ""
textLineThroughMode: ""
textLineThroughStyle: ""
textLineThroughWidth: ""
textOverflow: ""
textOverline: ""
textOverlineColor: ""
textOverlineMode: ""
textOverlineStyle: ""
textOverlineWidth: ""
textRendering: ""
textShadow: ""
textTransform: ""
textUnderline: ""
textUnderlineColor: ""
textUnderlineMode: ""
textUnderlineStyle: ""
textUnderlineWidth: ""
top: ""
unicodeBidi: ""
unicodeRange: ""
vectorEffect: ""
verticalAlign: ""
visibility: ""
webkitAnimation: ""
webkitAnimationDelay: ""
webkitAnimationDirection: ""
webkitAnimationDuration: ""
webkitAnimationFillMode: ""
webkitAnimationIterationCount: ""
webkitAnimationName: ""
webkitAnimationPlayState: ""
webkitAnimationTimingFunction: ""
webkitAppearance: ""
webkitAspectRatio: ""
webkitBackfaceVisibility: ""
webkitBackgroundClip: ""
webkitBackgroundComposite: ""
webkitBackgroundOrigin: ""
webkitBackgroundSize: ""
webkitBorderAfter: ""
webkitBorderAfterColor: ""
webkitBorderAfterStyle: ""
webkitBorderAfterWidth: ""
webkitBorderBefore: ""
webkitBorderBeforeColor: ""
webkitBorderBeforeStyle: ""
webkitBorderBeforeWidth: ""
webkitBorderEnd: ""
webkitBorderEndColor: ""
webkitBorderEndStyle: ""
webkitBorderEndWidth: ""
webkitBorderFit: ""
webkitBorderHorizontalSpacing: ""
webkitBorderImage: ""
webkitBorderRadius: ""
webkitBorderStart: ""
webkitBorderStartColor: ""
webkitBorderStartStyle: ""
webkitBorderStartWidth: ""
webkitBorderVerticalSpacing: ""
webkitBoxAlign: ""
webkitBoxDirection: ""
webkitBoxFlex: ""
webkitBoxFlexGroup: ""
webkitBoxLines: ""
webkitBoxOrdinalGroup: ""
webkitBoxOrient: ""
webkitBoxPack: ""
webkitBoxReflect: ""
webkitBoxShadow: ""
webkitColorCorrection: ""
webkitColumnAxis: ""
webkitColumnBreakAfter: ""
webkitColumnBreakBefore: ""
webkitColumnBreakInside: ""
webkitColumnCount: ""
webkitColumnGap: ""
webkitColumnRule: ""
webkitColumnRuleColor: ""
webkitColumnRuleStyle: ""
webkitColumnRuleWidth: ""
webkitColumnSpan: ""
webkitColumnWidth: ""
webkitColumns: ""
webkitDashboardRegion: ""
webkitFilter: ""
webkitFontFeatureSettings: ""
webkitFontKerning: ""
webkitFontSizeDelta: ""
webkitFontSmoothing: ""
webkitFontVariantLigatures: ""
webkitGridColumn: ""
webkitGridColumns: ""
webkitGridRow: ""
webkitGridRows: ""
webkitHighlight: ""
webkitHyphenateCharacter: ""
webkitHyphenateLimitAfter: ""
webkitHyphenateLimitBefore: ""
webkitHyphenateLimitLines: ""
webkitHyphens: ""
webkitLineAlign: ""
webkitLineBoxContain: ""
webkitLineBreak: ""
webkitLineClamp: ""
webkitLineGrid: ""
webkitLineSnap: ""
webkitLocale: ""
webkitLogicalHeight: ""
webkitLogicalWidth: ""
webkitMarginAfter: ""
webkitMarginAfterCollapse: ""
webkitMarginBefore: ""
webkitMarginBeforeCollapse: ""
webkitMarginBottomCollapse: ""
webkitMarginCollapse: ""
webkitMarginEnd: ""
webkitMarginStart: ""
webkitMarginTopCollapse: ""
webkitMarquee: ""
webkitMarqueeDirection: ""
webkitMarqueeIncrement: ""
webkitMarqueeRepetition: ""
webkitMarqueeSpeed: ""
webkitMarqueeStyle: ""
webkitMask: ""
webkitMaskAttachment: ""
webkitMaskBoxImage: ""
webkitMaskBoxImageOutset: ""
webkitMaskBoxImageRepeat: ""
webkitMaskBoxImageSlice: ""
webkitMaskBoxImageSource: ""
webkitMaskBoxImageWidth: ""
webkitMaskClip: ""
webkitMaskComposite: ""
webkitMaskImage: ""
webkitMaskOrigin: ""
webkitMaskPosition: ""
webkitMaskPositionX: ""
webkitMaskPositionY: ""
webkitMaskRepeat: ""
webkitMaskRepeatX: ""
webkitMaskRepeatY: ""
webkitMaskSize: ""
webkitMatchNearestMailBlockquoteColor: ""
webkitMaxLogicalHeight: ""
webkitMaxLogicalWidth: ""
webkitMinLogicalHeight: ""
webkitMinLogicalWidth: ""
webkitNbspMode: ""
webkitPaddingAfter: ""
webkitPaddingBefore: ""
webkitPaddingEnd: ""
webkitPaddingStart: ""
webkitPerspective: ""
webkitPerspectiveOrigin: ""
webkitPerspectiveOriginX: ""
webkitPerspectiveOriginY: ""
webkitPrintColorAdjust: ""
webkitRtlOrdering: ""
webkitSvgShadow: ""
webkitTextCombine: ""
webkitTextDecorationsInEffect: ""
webkitTextEmphasis: ""
webkitTextEmphasisColor: ""
webkitTextEmphasisPosition: ""
webkitTextEmphasisStyle: ""
webkitTextFillColor: ""
webkitTextOrientation: ""
webkitTextSecurity: ""
webkitTextSizeAdjust: ""
webkitTextStroke: ""
webkitTextStrokeColor: ""
webkitTextStrokeWidth: ""
webkitTransform: ""
webkitTransformOrigin: ""
webkitTransformOriginX: ""
webkitTransformOriginY: ""
webkitTransformOriginZ: ""
webkitTransformStyle: ""
webkitTransition: ""
webkitTransitionDelay: ""
webkitTransitionDuration: ""
webkitTransitionProperty: ""
webkitTransitionTimingFunction: ""
webkitUserDrag: ""
webkitUserModify: ""
webkitUserSelect: ""
webkitWritingMode: ""
whiteSpace: ""
widows: ""
width: ""
wordBreak: ""
wordSpacing: ""
wordWrap: ""
writingMode: ""
zIndex: ""
zoom: ""
__proto__: CSSStyleDeclarationPrototype
getPropertyCSSValue: function getPropertyCSSValue() {
getPropertyPriority: function getPropertyPriority() {
getPropertyShorthand: function getPropertyShorthand() {
getPropertyValue: function getPropertyValue() {
isPropertyImplicit: function isPropertyImplicit() {
item: function item() {
removeProperty: function removeProperty() {
setProperty: function setProperty() {
__proto__: Object
```

**Detailed**

```
console.log(document.getElementById('textBox1').style.color);
```

..will result in:

```
color: "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
```

**Looping (basic example, might need to be refined)**

```
var styles = document.getElementById('textBox1').style;

for (var i in styles) {
    if (
        i !== '0'
        && styles[i] != ''
        && styles[i] != undefined
        && styles[i] != null
        && styles.hasOwnProperty(i)
        && styles[i].length != undefined) {

        console.log(i + ' : ' + styles[i] + ' : ' + styles[i].length);
    }
}
```

..returns:

```
color : rgb(255, 255, 255) : 18
cssText : color: rgb(255, 255, 255);  : 27
```

**Notes**

These calls don't seem to fetch the inherited styles! For example if the parent of the Node has `font-size: 16px`, the `fontSize` property will *not* be inherited. So you have to walk the DOM tree until you reach the actual Node and then collect all styles. Yet this also requires you to know which will be inherited and which won't. This will be a big hassle to do code-wise.

If anyone can comment on to do this more efficient, I'm all ears :)

**More variance**

If you use the Stylesheet calls you will get a method to call the `parentStyle`, like so:

```
var rules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;

//console.log(rules);

for (var i in rules) {
    var selector = rules[i].selectorText;

    if (selector != undefined) {
        var regex = selector.match(/textBox1/g);

        if (regex !== null && regex.length > 0) {
            console.log(rules[i].style);
        }
    }
}
```

..you will find this info inside:

```
parentRule: CSSStyleRule
constructor: CSSStyleRuleConstructor
cssText: "#textBox1 { color: red; }"
parentRule: null
parentStyleSheet: CSSStyleSheet
selectorText: "#textBox1"
style: CSSStyleDeclaration
type: 1
__proto__: CSSStyleRulePrototype
```

Be aware that this method requires you to have set all styles through the Stylesheet you are calling. This example also only works as selecting the first stylesheet found. If you have more than one stylesheet, you will need to loop-match or know the index up front.

**Resources**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty
- [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome developer tools, by right-clicking the footer and clicking "Inspect element", you can browse though the elements and see the CSS styles.